# JSP Using Custom Classes from WEB-INF

Tags: java, class, jsp, import

I'm having some issue when trying to utilize one of my Java classes inside a JSP web application (tomcat).

I have my class sitting inside the WEB-INF directory (compiled as well)

```
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/c_myclass.java
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/c_myclass.class

package myclass;

public class c_myclass {

    // class variable
    String classvar;

    // constructor
    public c_myclass(String arg) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // class function
    public void classfunc(String arg) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

I have my index.jsp sitting in the root of my app directory

```
/approot/index.jsp

// these seems to work
<%@ page import = "java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import = "myclass.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Nothing</title>
</head>

<body>
<%!
    // global var for testing
    // this fails
    public static c_myclass myClass;
%>
</body>

</html>
```

I've done something pretty similar in regular Java and it worked but here I am getting an error and am not sure why

```
c_appclasses cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason it doesn't work, it has to do with the WEB-INF directory. It needs to be layed out according to the name of the package so for my case.

```
package myclass;

public class c_myclass {

    // class variable
    String classvar;

    // constructor
    public c_myclass(String arg) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // class function
    public void classfunc(String arg) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

The package name is myclass so it needs to be inside a directory named myclass

```
package myclass;
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/myclass/c_myclass.java
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/myclass/c_myclass.class
```

If the package name has additional stops then WEB-INF will need additional subdirectories.

```
package com.myclass;
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/com/myclass/c_myclass.java
/approot/WEB-INF/classes/com/myclass/c_myclass.class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted the Java Source code file inside the WEB-INF directory, it won't work since source code is not actually running on your machine.

First, you have to compile the java file into a class file - bytecode that is interpreted by your java virtual machine.

---

AFAIK, you can not use keywords like `public` or `static` like that in a JSP file. JSP is not a class definition but rather just source code interpreted on runtime by your servlet engine. Everything you write in a JSP block like that is practically in a method context.

---

In other terms, maybe you should consider checking out a guide / tutorial for Java WEB MVC. Your setup is pretty bad practise.

Comment: Thanks for your response, are there any that you would recommend?

Comment: Personally, I prefer using Spring web mvc. Aside from the official guide there are a lot of tutorials out there. I can not recommend any, but I'm sure google will help you out.

Comment: Even after compiling the class it still doesn't work though. It's saying it cannot be resolved